# How long does it take for an android application to be placed in "standby" mode in M?

Tags: java, android, android-source, standby

Does anyone know the timing for this? Alternatively does anyone know which part of the AOSP source code concerns itself with app standby?

I found the equivalent timing for Doze (30 minutes, btw) by perusing the source code for [DeviceIdleController.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/DeviceIdleController.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F), looking to do the same for Standby.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "standby" mode?
AFAIK, your app can be either active,background or dead(killed).

How do you describe the state you think is "standby"?